# How to use API to invoke Lambda function

Tags: api, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Im trying to setup an API which will invoke a Lambda function. The function is written with Pyhton.
I have setup a URL Query parameter and also a mapping template.

When using the api URL I have added parameters at the end of the URL so I can invoke it

To get this working I believe I need to somehow add these parameters into my python script. Can anyone tell me how this is done?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4800344).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my code below
https://github.com/mmakadiya/aws_lambda-API_gateway-Import-XML-data

You can update the lambda function with below code
import JSON

def lambda_handler(event, context):

```
print("####################################")
print(event)
print("####################################")
# TODO implement
return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
}
```

---

When you will trigger a POST request like below
https://gjtf9q4422.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Dev?autooff=yes?autoon=no?testparam=haha

the "event" will print the query string like this. Simply you can grab it from the "event' parameter as well.

[query_string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOEe1.png)

Comment: Thanks. That cleared it up for me :-)